# jQuery mobile radio button onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="Boxing" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">Boxing</label>              
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="MMA"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">MMA</label>             
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="Kick-boxing"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">Kick-boxing</label>                     
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="custom"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-4">Custom</label>
</fieldset>
```

When the last radio button (radio-choice-4) is chosen, i want to open a dialog box. My javascript:

```
$("#radio-choice-4").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
    jQuery.mobile.changePage('#dialogCustom');
    console.log('custom is selected');
});
```

The change event does not fire and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: do you have this code in the dom ready handler ?

Comment: It is inside $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8NHY4/ `$(document).on("change", "#radio-choice-4", function (event, ui) {` dont use `.ready()` in jqm. check the demo.

Comment: .ready() is now changed to bind('pageinit',function(event). But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: What versions of jquery and JQM are you using?